# How to remove an invalidly-named file in Bash?

Tags: bash, invalid-characters

I found a file named '.|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png', and I really want to remove this. what should I do?

I tried to use `ls -al` to get the info of the file then I got this:

```
ls: cannot access '.|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png': No such file or directory
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 jinshengye jinshengye 4096 Jun  5 17:10 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 jinshengye jinshengye 4096 Jun  5 16:58 ..
-????????? ? ?          ?             ?            ? .|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is a common FAQ, but it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Try searching for similar questions on [unix.se] or [su]

Comment: all right,  may I delete this post?

Comment: When there are multiple answers, you can't any longer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the inode number(s) with

```
ls -li
```

And remove it with

```
find . -inum 1234 -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, however it does not work. I tried `ls -li`, it gives `total 0`....

Comment: Then your problem is not a regular file with a weird name, but probably a corrupted filesystem. You should run a tool like `fsck` (if this is Linux) or Windows's ChkDsk, depending on the platform / filesystem you have.

Comment: I tried `chkdsk \f \r \x`, it gives a long list: `Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

...
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

...


Deleted invalid filename .|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png (6DEA5) in directory 6DAC5.

...

Deleting index entry .|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png in index $I30 of file 6DAC5.

...

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...

...

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Progress: 0 of 2317642 done; Stage:  0%; Total:  0%; ETA: 696:06:01 ..`, it costs long time.. I will give you feed back, many thx

Comment: it works, the file was removed. Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

OK you can try deleting with quotes

```
rm ".|rst412slp10lad10_noTopo.png"
```

but that probably won't work, you may need to set rights and /or reboot (or more)... Have a look at this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa